# Creating a formula that queries data in Column B based on a selection from Column A in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am reasonably familiar with Excel formulas but I need to construct a more complex query and am not having much success at the moment.

I have simplified what I am trying to achieve for the purpose of the question.

Here is my source data:

[image]

What I am trying to do is construct a formula which will summarise the 'fed' status of each AnimalType. Here is a long hand version of what I am trying to do:

Using the range A1:A7, IF values in Column B = "Fed" WHERE AnimalType = "Cat" display 'All Animals Fed' ELSE display "All Animals Not Fed". Therefore, the output I would see for this table (using the conditional formatting rule) would be:

[image]

I hope this example provides enough detail for what I am trying to do. The actual solution I need is slightly more complicated than this but if I figure out how to to the above I am fairly confident I can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select `B1:B2` cells in your "Recap" sheet, and type this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A$1:$A$2&"Not Fed", Animals!A$2:A$7&Animals!B$2:B$7, 0)), "All Animals Fed", "All Animals Not Fed")
```

This is an array formula, so you need to "validate" it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In order to work, you need to replace "Cats" with "Cat" and "Dogs" with "Dog", or you can adapt the formula to delete last character.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this but get "All Animals Fed" in column B, and beneath that a zero. I can see the principle of what the formula is attempting to do though. Is there any way I could send you the file to take a look?

Comment: Did you press Ctrl+Shift+Enter? Yes, please upload your file on a file hosting service.

Comment: I did. When I tried to fill down the formula I also got a circular reference error? Have now added the file here - thanks for your help with this. http://tbf.me/a/EF9B9

Comment: My bad, there is an error in my formula. I forgot "Animals" sheet name for `$B$2:$B$7` array, so it targets the wrong sheet (`Sheet2`). I've updated my answer, sorry again.

Comment: This is brilliant thank you! I did actually spot that sheet ref was missing earlier and add it myself, but then I think I must have forgotten to validate the function so assumed it wasn't working still. :) There is one slight modification to your answer - you mentioned highlighting B1:B2 and typing that function - if the same formula is applied to both rows I don't get the required result, so instead I have modified it slightly to ...(MATCH($A$1&"Not Fed"... in B1 and ...(MATCH($A$2&"Not Fed"... in B2. Thanks again!

Comment: ssssteffff, as embarassed as I am to admit it - I have fallen at the next hurdle. If you were able to take a look that would be awesome: http://superuser.com/questions/745704/can-i-use-the-excel-match-function-to-match-on-more-than-one-type-of-value

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Pivot Table (Insert ribbon) from the range. I would drag the AnimalType field to the Row Labels zone, and the Fed? Field to the Column Labels zone. I would drag the AnimalType field to the Values zone.

This will give you a count of Animals by type and Fed status, with row and column totals. These can answer all the questions you are trying to answer, without coding any formulas, in a structure that can easily be extended to include other columns.