# Find and Assign (Exact Phrase) Keyword Values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using the following formula to assign values to rows based on keywords, which I found here: [Can I use the Excel Match function to match on more than one type of value](https://superuser.com/questions/745704/can-i-use-the-excel-match-function-to-match-on-more-than-one-type-of-value)

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(C$1,$A2)),"",C$1)
```

Is there a way to append this formula so it only assigns the exact phrase/word? To give you an example, I am searching my content for the keyword Lab, the above formula brings up Lab, but also finds it in other words eg Labratory, Labour etc. I need it to only find the exact word "Lab".

Comment: In your case does "Lab" get followed or preceded by a space at all?

Comment: Hi Eric, yes "Lab" would be a single individual word with space before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, since there is a space before and after the word then you can simply modify your formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(C$1,$A2)),"",C$1)
```

to be

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("" & C$1 & " ",$A2)),"",C$1)
```

The spaces will make it so "Lab" doesn't get found in Labratory.

Comment: Also do you see the logic as to WHY it works for future problems?

Comment: Yes, it's very clear now :-), your first question already did it!